# React native and Expo Sqlite, querying by date with timestamp field

Tags: sqlite, react-native, expo

I have an app running in react native using Expo Sqlite solution for database. Everything has worked great for me in terms of creating tables, records and querying for basics.

My problem is that I now need to query based on date/time for graphing. So in some sections I would like to get an average of records within a time frame (all records from this date to this date)

I've got a baisc table creation script here:

```
txn.executeSql(
          'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS activityStatus(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, activity INT(10), activityDate TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)',
          []
        );
```

So I have a field where it's a timestamp and defaults to current (this all works fine)

I have a query like `Select activity, activityDate from activityStatus` which returns rows but I'm curious how I can now query records for certain dates, like in the event that I want an average of all activity where activityDate is between '2019-07-01' and '2019-07-31'

How can I do this with my current setup using sqlite (specifically expo sqlite)

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
SELECT * FROM activityStatus AS a
WHERE a.activityDate
BETWEEN '2019-07-01' AND strftime('%Y-%m-%d', 'now')
ORDER BY a.activityDate DESC
```